# Obter campos nulos do banco com LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tenho uma tabela de `Gestor` no banco onde guarda informações de um usuário com perfil de Gestor. Nessa tabela, tenho duas `FK's`: **uniaoId** e **escolaId**. Pois bem, esse gestor TEM que pertencer a uma união e pode, ou não, pertencer a uma escola.
Aí é que está o meu problema. Na hora que eu faço o join com linq, ele não traz os gestores que não pertencem a uma escola. Já tentei o seguinte, mas não funcionou:

```
var listaRelatorioEmail = (
    from ge in db.Gestor
        join uni in db.Uniao on ge.UniaoId equals uni.UniaoId into uni_join
    from uni in uni_join.DefaultIfEmpty()                                               
        join es in db.Escola on ge.EscolaId equals es.EscolaId into es_join
    from es in es_join.DefaultIfEmpty()                                                 
        select new
        {
            UniaoNome = uni.Nome,
            UniaoId = uni.UniaoId,
            EscolaNome = es.Nome,
            EscolaId = es.EscolaId,
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optei em fazer a mesma coisa com *Extension Methods*. Funcionou perfeitamente com o seguinte código:

```
var listaRelatorioEmail = db.Gestor.Select(a => new
                             {
                                 UniaoNome = a.Nome,
                                 UniaoId = a.UniaoEntidadeId,
                                 EscolaNome = a.Nome,
                                 EscolaId = a.EscolaId == null ? 0 : a.EscolaId.Value
                             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

não sei se entendi bem mas,
tente mudar o join da escola para left join pois assim ele tras todos os gestores e se n tiver escola ele coloca null se não me engano

```
var listaRelatorioEmail = (
from ge in db.Gestor
    join uni in db.Uniao on ge.UniaoId equals uni.UniaoId into uni_join
from uni in uni_join.DefaultIfEmpty()                                               
    **left join** es in db.Escola on ge.EscolaId equals es.EscolaId into es_join
from es in es_join.DefaultIfEmpty()                                                 
    select new
    {
        UniaoNome = uni.Nome,
        UniaoId = uni.UniaoId,
        EscolaNome = es.Nome,
        EscolaId = es.EscolaId,
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Não existe left join no LINQ.